# Kernel errors while trying to use widescreen monitor with AMDGPU on manjaro

Tags: manjaro, display, amd-graphics

I'm having trouble getting a widescreen monitor to work (the Samsung odyssey g9). It doesn't seem to detect any resolutions bar the fallback defaults. I've tried multiple kernel versions and had the same problem. Currently, on linux511 I get this in dmesg.

```
Feb 24 11:41:59 ben-pc kernel: [drm] perform_link_training_with_retries: Link training attempt 1 of 4 failed
Feb 24 11:41:59 ben-pc kernel: [drm] perform_link_training_with_retries: Link training attempt 2 of 4 failed
Feb 24 11:42:00 ben-pc kernel: [drm] perform_link_training_with_retries: Link training attempt 3 of 4 failed
Feb 24 11:42:00 ben-pc kernel: [drm] enabling link 0 failed: 15
Feb 24 11:42:01 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_remove_stream_from_ctx [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Pipe not found for stream 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:42:01 ben-pc kernel: [drm:handle_hpd_irq [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Restoring old state failed with -22
Feb 24 11:42:03 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:42:08 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:42:13 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:42:18 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:42:22 ben-pc pulseaudio[3661]: ALSA woke us up to write new data to the device, but there was actually nothing to write.
Feb 24 11:42:22 ben-pc pulseaudio[3661]: Most likely this is a bug in the ALSA driver 'snd_usb_audio'. Please report this issue to the ALSA developers.
Feb 24 11:42:22 ben-pc pulseaudio[3661]: We were woken up with POLLOUT set -- however a subsequent snd_pcm_avail() returned 0 or another value < min_avail.
Feb 24 11:42:24 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:42:29 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:42:34 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:42:39 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:42:44 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:42:49 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:42:54 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:42:59 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:43:04 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:43:09 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:43:14 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:43:15 ben-pc dunst[3664]: WARNING: No icon found in path: 'system-software-install-symbolic'
Feb 24 11:43:19 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:43:24 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:43:29 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:43:34 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:43:35 ben-pc dbus-daemon[1600]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.51' (uid=1000 pid=6278 comm="/usr/lib/slack/slack ")
Feb 24 11:43:35 ben-pc systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Feb 24 11:43:39 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:43:44 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:43:49 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:43:54 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:43:59 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:44:00 ben-pc dbus-daemon[1600]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Feb 24 11:44:04 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:44:09 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:44:14 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:44:19 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:44:24 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:44:29 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:44:34 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:44:39 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:44:44 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:44:49 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:44:54 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:44:59 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:45:04 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:45:09 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:45:14 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:45:19 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:45:24 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:45:29 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:45:34 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:45:39 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:45:44 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:45:49 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:45:54 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:45:59 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:46:04 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:46:09 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:46:14 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:46:19 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:46:24 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:46:29 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:46:34 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:46:39 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:46:44 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:46:49 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:46:54 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:46:59 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:47:04 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:47:09 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:47:14 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:47:19 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:47:25 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:47:30 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:47:35 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:47:40 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:47:45 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:47:50 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:47:55 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:48:00 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:48:05 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:48:10 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:48:15 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:48:20 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:48:21 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_remove_stream_from_ctx [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Pipe not found for stream 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:48:21 ben-pc kernel: [drm:handle_hpd_irq [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Restoring old state failed with -22
Feb 24 11:48:25 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:48:30 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:48:35 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:48:40 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:48:45 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:48:50 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:48:55 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_add_plane_to_context [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Head pipe not found for stream_state 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:48:59 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_remove_stream_from_ctx [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Pipe not found for stream 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:48:59 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_remove_stream_from_ctx [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Pipe not found for stream 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:48:59 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_remove_stream_from_ctx [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Pipe not found for stream 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:48:59 ben-pc kernel: ------------[ cut here ]------------
Feb 24 11:48:59 ben-pc kernel: atomic remove_fb failed with -22
Feb 24 11:48:59 ben-pc kernel: WARNING: CPU: 10 PID: 362 at drivers/gpu/drm/drm_framebuffer.c:1113 drm_framebuffer_remove+0x3f0/0x450 [drm]
Feb 24 11:48:59 ben-pc kernel: Modules linked in: xt_nat xt_tcpudp veth xt_conntrack xt_MASQUERADE nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xt_addrtype iptable_filter iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c br_netfilter bridge stp llc overlay nct6775 hwmon_vid lm92 uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common videodev joydev mousedev corsair_cpro squashfs nls_iso8859_1 vfat fat loop igb snd_usb_audio snd_usbmidi_li>
Feb 24 11:48:59 ben-pc kernel:  ttm snd_hwdep kvm drm_kms_helper soundwire_bus cec snd_soc_core drm irqbypass snd_compress ac97_bus crct10dif_pclmul snd_pcm_dmaengine crc32_pclmul snd_pcm ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel snd_timer ccp agpgart snd crypto_simd syscopyarea cryptd sysfillrect glue_helper sp5100_tco sysimgblt nvidia(POE) rapl pcspkr soundcore k10temp fb_sys_fops i2c_piix4 rng_core wmi pinctrl_amd mac_hid acpi_cpufreq vboxnetflt(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxdrv(O>
Feb 24 11:48:59 ben-pc kernel: CPU: 10 PID: 362 Comm: kworker/10:2 Tainted: P           OE     5.11.0-1-MANJARO #1
Feb 24 11:48:59 ben-pc kernel: Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/ROG STRIX X570-F GAMING, BIOS 2203 06/17/2020
Feb 24 11:48:59 ben-pc kernel: Workqueue: events drm_mode_rmfb_work_fn [drm]
Feb 24 11:48:59 ben-pc kernel: RIP: 0010:drm_framebuffer_remove+0x3f0/0x450 [drm]
Feb 24 11:48:59 ben-pc kernel: Code: ff ff 4c 89 f7 e8 f0 bf ff ff 4c 89 f7 e8 38 be ff ff c7 44 24 08 f4 ff ff ff 8b 74 24 08 48 c7 c7 e8 f1 a0 c2 e8 4e 8b 2c f3 <0f> 0b e9 48 fe ff ff be 03 00 00 00 48 89 ef e8 9c 3c cf f2 e9 10
Feb 24 11:48:59 ben-pc kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffa81043a8bde0 EFLAGS: 00010282
Feb 24 11:48:59 ben-pc kernel: RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffffa2ca35c81600 RCX: 0000000000000000
Feb 24 11:48:59 ben-pc kernel: RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: ffffffffb659e7bf RDI: 00000000ffffffff
Feb 24 11:48:59 ben-pc kernel: RBP: ffffa2cb72ac0f00 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: ffffa81043a8bc20
Feb 24 11:48:59 ben-pc kernel: R10: ffffa81043a8bc18 R11: ffffa2d94f2a6fa8 R12: ffffa2ca1d2e0300
Feb 24 11:48:59 ben-pc kernel: R13: ffffa2ca1d2e02f8 R14: ffffa81043a8be00 R15: ffffa2ca840f9840
Feb 24 11:48:59 ben-pc kernel: FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffffa2d90ec80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Feb 24 11:48:59 ben-pc kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Feb 24 11:48:59 ben-pc kernel: CR2: 0000560f385d67f8 CR3: 000000014c652000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0
Feb 24 11:48:59 ben-pc kernel: Call Trace:
Feb 24 11:48:59 ben-pc kernel:  drm_mode_rmfb_work_fn+0x3c/0x50 [drm]
Feb 24 11:48:59 ben-pc kernel:  process_one_work+0x214/0x3e0
Feb 24 11:48:59 ben-pc kernel:  worker_thread+0x1f9/0x3d0
Feb 24 11:48:59 ben-pc kernel:  ? rescuer_thread+0x3c0/0x3c0
Feb 24 11:48:59 ben-pc kernel:  kthread+0x142/0x160
Feb 24 11:48:59 ben-pc kernel:  ? __kthread_bind_mask+0x60/0x60
Feb 24 11:48:59 ben-pc kernel:  ret_from_fork+0x22/0x30
Feb 24 11:48:59 ben-pc kernel: ---[ end trace ceac49e4b7a5c3d8 ]---
Feb 24 11:49:05 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_remove_stream_from_ctx [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Pipe not found for stream 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:49:05 ben-pc kernel: [drm:handle_hpd_irq [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Restoring old state failed with -22
Feb 24 11:49:21 ben-pc kernel: [drm:dc_remove_stream_from_ctx [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Pipe not found for stream 00000000f8c12124 !
Feb 24 11:49:21 ben-pc kernel: [drm:handle_hpd_irq [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Restoring old state failed with -22
```

I'm on manjaro with X11, and using an AMD 5700xt GPU. There's been different suggestions on forums about adding custom resolutions but I've had no luck with these either. I could try patch my kernel by hand but I'd rather not if I don't have to

Answer (score 0):

Does this post help you at all?: https://www.reddit.com/r/ultrawidemasterrace/comments/k4tt7j/linux_woes_with_samsung_odyssey_g9/

Comment: Unfortunately, I've come across that reddit post alright and I had no luck

Comment: Try filing a bug on the Linux kernel Bugzilla page here: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/ or contacting Samsung: https://www.samsung.com/ie/support/model/LC49G95TSSUXEN/#contact.